# "Program has stopped working"

Tags: c, arrays, string, for-loop, while-loop

When I run the program the first `for` loop works just fine but then I get the `"Program has stopped working"` message before going into the second `while` loop. Is there an error in my coding and if so how can I fix it?

```
#include<stdio.h>

double Combat(int x, int y, char mons[20]);


int  main(void)
{
    int monsters, i, target, alive;

    while(1)
    {
        printf("ENTERING COMBAT\n\nHow many monsters?> ");
        scanf(" %d", &monsters);
        char monster[monsters][20];
        int monstermaxhp[monsters];
        int monsterhp[monsters];
        for(i=0;i<monsters;++i)
        {
            printf("\n\nNO SPACES\n\nEnter Monster %d's name> ", i+1);
            scanf("%s", &monster[i]);
            printf("\n\nEnter %s's hitpoints> ", monster[i]);
            scanf("%d", &monstermaxhp[i]);
            monsterhp[i]=monstermaxhp[i];
        }
            alive=1;
            while(alive==1)
        {
          for(i=0;i<monsters;++i)
        {
            printf("\n\n%d:%s%3c%3d/%d", i+1, ' ',monsterhp[i],monstermaxhp[i]);
        }
        printf("\n\nSelect Target> ");
        scanf("%d", &target);
        i=target-1;
        monsterhp[i]=Combat(monsterhp[i],monstermaxhp[i],monster[i]);
        for(i=0;i<monsters;++i)
        {
            if(monsterhp[i]<=0)
                alive=0;
        }
        }
    }
    return(0);
}


double Combat(int x, int y, char mons[20])
{
    int damage, plrroll, monroll;

    printf("\nRoll for %s> ", mons);
    scanf("%d", &monroll);
    printf("\nRoll for Player> ");
    scanf("%d", &plrroll);
    if(plrroll>monroll)
    {
        printf("\nHIT! Roll for damage> ");
        scanf("%d", &damage);
        x=x-damage;
    }
    else
    {
        printf("\nMISS! :P\n");
    }
    return(x);
}
```

Comment: Have you tried stepping through you program using a debugger? And please indent properly...

Comment: Please show terminal contents from when you run this and it fails.

Comment: I don't know if this is by design or you simply missed it .. you are declaring arrays `monster`,`monstermaxhp` and `monsterhp` everytime you loop in outer while

Answer (score 2):

Change:

```
printf("\n\n%d:%s%3c%3d/%d", i+1, ' ',monsterhp[i],monstermaxhp[i]);
```

to

```
printf("\n\n%d: %s   %3d/%d", i+1, monster[i], monsterhp[i], monstermaxhp[i]);
```

You're trying to printf in the wrong order. I think you missed out the monster's name! There's no need for the 3 spaces using %c either, so I've inlined the spaces in your format string instead.

You now get an output like:

> 1: Good    1/1
>
> 2: Evil    2/2

Comment: lol, just noticed that looking back at the code and fixed it, came back here to take down the question and saw this comment.

Answer (score 0):

Ok just a few problems with your code :

1. you are declaring arrays : monster,monstermaxhp and monsterhp everytime you loop in outer while
2. its not `return(0);` .. its `return 0;`
3. in for loop do post increment  ( change `++i` to `i++`)
4. Fix your printf statement to this:

   `printf("\n\n%d:%s%3c%3d/%d", i+1, monsterhp[i], ' ', monstermaxhp[i]);`
5. Also change :

   `scanf("%s", &monster[i]);`

   to this:

   `scanf("%s", monster[i]);`